# Running Python script in Abaqus in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, permissions, python, scripts

I am running a python script through the scripting interface in Abaqus. It's a basic script that writes a value from each element from the abaqus simulation into a a text file. The text file is then used by another python file (call it "sample.py") to perform an additional calculation.

I am having an issue calling the "sample.py" file from within abaqus. When the script tries to open the "sample.py" file I get:

`IOError: 13 Permission denied`

I have changed the permissions of the file to allow read, write and execute for the file owner, groups and others however the same error appears. In fact, running the script actually removes the read, write and execute privileges for the owner and groups but keeps them for other.

I have run this script on windows and it runs fine. I am running this file from the home directory so `sudo` access should not be an issue. Anyone have any ideas?